# Laravel encode/decode ajax url

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Controller:

```
public function ajaxsearch(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $output = "";
            $productindex = Product::where('product_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->states . '%')->take(4)->get();

            if ($productindex) {
                foreach ($productindex as $key => $value) {
                    $output .= '<div>
                                <img src="/images/'. $value->slidephoto->first()->sm_photo .'.jpg" width="400px">
                                <h3>'. $value->product_name .'</h3>
                                </div>';
                }
                return Response($output);
            }
        }
        return view('main.ajax');
    }
```

jquery:

```
$('#searchinput').on('keyup', function(){
      $value=$(this).val();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '{{URL::to('ajaxsearch')}}',
        data: {'states':$value},
        success:function(data){
          $('#fixedsearch').html(data);

        }
      });
    });
```

When ajax fetches a value which is not in english I get this problem in my console log.

```
191.js:5 GET http://localhost:8000/ajaxsearch?states=%CF%80 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I am using Laravel 5.1 and jquery v. 1.9.1.
The foreign language I use as additional is the Greek that I have this specific problem.

Comment: It is saying your PHP script CRASHED the server

Comment: it works in English

Comment: Check your `laravel.log` file to get more detail about the error.

Comment: I didn't get any logs from laravel for this error.

Comment: There is no pi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have URL encoded characters passed in, you can simply use `urldecode` to convert them back into their correct characters.

Because URL encoded characters are basically strings containing percent signs, this *really* confuses SQL when you concatenate with more percent signs.

`Product::where('product_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->states . '%')`

`$request->states` is `%CF%80`, so SQL created will look like `... from product where product_name like %%CF%80%` - the percentage signs make no sense within a `like` check.

Instead, `Product::where('product_name', 'LIKE', '%' . urldecode($request->states) . '%')`

`$request->states` is now `π`, so SQL created will look like `... from product where product_name like %π%`.

Comment: I have the same error. Why? But I think you are close for the solution.

Comment: I tried so far the utf8_encode() and urlencode(). By these functions I didn't get any errors but also I didn't get results from greek. Urldecode() is not working.

Comment: What's not working for you with `urldecode`? What is your expected result from `urldecode` and what is the actual result?

Comment: Urldecode is not working.

191.js:5 GET http://localhost:8000/ajaxsearch?states=%CF%80 500 (Internal Server Error)send @ 191.js:5ajax @ 191.js:5(anonymous function) @ (index):442dispatch @ 191.js:3v.handle @ 191.js:3

Comment: Untill after the Product statement is perfect. Something in if statement is wrong and the code is collapse to above error. I guess I should do something more in foreach or value output statement. I am troubleshooting at this now.

Comment: After many hours I found the solution. It was $value->slidephoto->first()->sm_photo which was a null value.

Comment: for url decode, how do i override the entire $request parameter that need to be decoded.

Cause i need to use laravel validate..
Thank you

Answer (score -2):

try using encodeURI() javscript function

```
$('#searchinput').on('keyup', function(){
      $value=$(this).val();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '{{URL::to('ajaxsearch')}}',
        data: {'states':encodeURI($value)},
        success:function(data){
          $('#fixedsearch').html(data);

        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: I haven't errors and I haven't the greek results only the english. Why?

Comment: can you check the request parameters in developer console are they going correct?

Comment: I SOLVE the problem as you see in above answers.  It was $value->slidephoto->first()->sm_photo. When it is null value the urldecode doesn't take affect somehow (the decoding). That's a strange and I don't know how to solve this little issue.